# Amazon SES Unsubscribe list with PHP

Tags: email, amazon-ses

I have used amazon SES service for email campaigning. PHP Class that I am using can be found at http://www.orderingdisorder.com/aws/ses/.

I want to place a link in html mail that will be used to unsubscribe that user from list. I am sending mail to a list of users however, I want link to be unique for each. Link should appear as
        http://www.mydomain.com/mail_unsub.php?userid=mymails@gmail.com&key=kjhgporhfs

Is there any function in SES that I can use directly??
suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

You could place a special tag like #unsub# at the footer. When you loop through the mail list, you need to replace unsub tag with the current user email ( add the http://mydomain.com too of course)

When user click on that link, you need to remove them from you list. Or mark it as unsubscribe. It should be done inside mail_unsubscribe.php

Comment: @ Granit thanks for the reply. I am passing list of emails in bcc and template to SES server from where the actual mails are dispatched, the problem is, I cannot iterate the loop for single mail ID. I hope you understand the problem now..

Comment: @Mahendra, you need to have the email send to individuals, not a list.  The email is static once it is sent and if you are sending to a group of folks (i.e. to: addr1@somewhere.com, addr2@somewhere.com, addr3@somewhere.com, etc) the email won't have a unique unsub link for each person.  That is something you need to handle by sending a single email.